# Firebase rules variable not matching as string

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

so I am trying to match the user email with the collection name like below in my Firestore rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {  
    match /users/{userEmail} {
      allow read: if request.auth.token.email.matches(userEmail);      
    }
  }
}
```

I am aware its not good practice to set collection ID's as emails, but please assume it to be *any* string here. **The above does not work.** however, if I replace `request.auth.token.email.matches(userEmail)`   with `request.auth.token.email.matches("myemail@gmail.com")` it works fine.

[image]

Above I have a single document in my users collection with id = `myemail@gmail.com`, so why is it not matching when I use the `userEmail` variable but will match if I use "myemail@gmail.com" string?

*Additional Info:*
Request to `/getAccountInfo` you can see `myemail@gmail.com` as email
[image]

**App code**

I used Vuexfire for firestore binding.
`store/index.js`

```
bindUsers: firestoreAction(({bindFirestoreRef}) => {  
    return bindFirestoreRef("users", db.collection("users")
    .where('email', '==', 'myemail@gmail.com');
}),
```

`App.vue`

```
async mounted() {
    if (firebase.auth.currentUser) {
        // Bind Vuexfire after if/when user exists to capture Firestore changes
        await this.$store.dispatch("bindUsers");
    }
}
```

Comment: Security rules by themselves don't do anything.  They are only meaningful when paired with specific queries coming from a web or mobile app.  Please edit your question to show that code, and also demonstrate (perhaps by logging) that a user is signed in at the time of the query with the correct email address.

Comment: @DougStevenson I've updated my screenshot above. If `request.auth.token.email.matches("myemail@gmail.com")` works then wouldn't that confirm I have user auth when my app loads? Only when I replace with `userEmail` do I get `FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.`, and you can see from my screenshot the document name is `myemail@gmail.com` ... does it not like the @ maybe?

Comment: We need the client app code that performs the query, as I described in the first comment.  The screenshot is not telling the whole story.

Comment: I'm using Vuexfire to bind to my collection, [here](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/vuexfire/binding-subscriptions.html#binding-in-actions). I only start the binding once my app is mounted and `if (firebase.auth.currentUser)`. I'm still confused why it works if I update the rules to use the "myemail@gmail.com" string but not the {user} variable? << how could that work if this is a "client app code" issue considering the only document in the collection is "myemail@gmail.com"?

Comment: I don't think you can use the "userEmail" variable directly from the "match /users/{userEmail}" line (not 100% sure, but this might be why your current userEmail value is not valid.

Comment: Can you try something like "allow read: if request.auth.token.email.matches (request.resource.id)" instead?

Comment: What you added here is still not client code that performs the query that isn't working with these rules.  This is the most important part to provide, other than the rules.  It doesn't matter that you're using view binding or whatever - all that matters is the query code.

Comment: @nicksarno, tried that same result :(

Comment: @DougStevenson, I use a package, Vuexfire, that syncs fb collections with the browser so the queries I post would just be using that package... I'll see how much I can dig into how Vuexfire is making the queries tho

Comment: At the very least, yes, show what you've done with that package that implies a specific query is being done.

Comment: I kindly ask, along the other folks who did, for you to share the client code as it will help reproduce this issue

Comment: I've added the Vuexfire code that is used to sync Firestore data, albeit I don't know _exactly_ what it's doing under the hood. I guess what I'm confused at is, how does it matter how it's accessing ONE document? I only have myemail@gmail.com doc, so whether I access that entire users collection or not, there's only one record and as stated, works fine if my rules explicitly use that email as a string, but not that document id as a variable

Comment: @user1710344 I see that the good answer was provided by Doug. Do you need more help with this question?

Answer (score 1):

Your query is filtering on a document **property** called email (not its ID):

```
return bindFirestoreRef("users", db.collection("users")
.where('email', '==', 'myemail@gmail.com');
```

This has nothing to do with the email token in the user's Firebase Auth account.  You haven't shown that you have an email property in the document at all - all you have is a **document with an ID that contains an email address.**

Your query ultimately needs to match the rule that limits the query.  This means that you need some way of explicitly filtering on the client in a way that matches the constraints of the rule.  This means you're going to have to use a `get()` type query for the **specific document with an ID**, not a collection query that requires filtering with a where clause.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your help and patience :) Second... I think that's the magic piece I was missing, but let me confirm I understand correctly. In order to filter documents in a collection using a .where(), you'll need access to all docs so the .where() can "look inside each"?

Comment: In all cases, your query filters must match the constraints of the rules.  The rules will not filters results for you.  This is covered in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters).  If you query could possibly match any document that rules would disallow, then the entire query will fail.  Since your rules only allow a user to access the one document that matches their email address, your query should only ever attempt to get that one document, and nothing more.

Comment: Because I have one doc in my collection I could exclude my .where() all together (and understood rules are not filters). With my ONE doc in my collection, this rule works: `if request.auth.token.email.matches("myemail@gmail.com");` and this one does not `request.auth.token.email.matches(userEmail); ` << That to me is still confusing

Comment: It doesn't matter how many documents are in the collection.  The rules will still not accept query that **would** require a filter.  It's not going to check each one - that's not going to scale, and is essentially what a filter would have to do anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but it looks like you are writing your rule more like a filter than as a security rule.

@DougStevenson will know much better than me, but if you hard-code a string value then Firestore can determine explicitly if that rule will succeed or fail.  But if you use a variable, then I believe that Firestore determines whether the rule will return true or false in general - not specific runtime cases.  In this case, the rule should return `false` since there will be rows that fail the test.

It almost looks like you are trying to use your rule to filter out rows.  Firestore Rules don't work that way.

As Doug suggests, you should show us some client-side code you are using for accessing that collection so we can determine if the code is falling into the "rule trying to be a filter" trap.

Comment: I have updated my original comment with how I'm binding to Firestore. I understand that Firestore Rules do not apply filtering, but I am _attempting_ to do so as part of my query so that the filtered query will match the rules for that user. However, my test case in my comment is a single document (so its all or nothing). And my Rulles work fine if I hardcode the document id: "myemail@gmail.com" but will _not_ work if I use the documentId variable: "{userEmail}" (where only document in `users` is myemail@gmail.com). What else could I be querying from app that would cause this 1-1 to break?